# retrofit 2 json response json array and object

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have this type of response. How to handle in retrofit2?

```
{
    "content": {
        "customer": null,
        "vehicle": null,
        "inspectionLibrary": [
            {
                "id": 761,
                "desc": "16 point - GM57",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 758,
                "desc": "20 point courtsey",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 762,
                "desc": "33 point courtsey",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 766,
                "desc": "42 point courtsey",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 747,
                "desc": "A/C system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 869,
                "desc": "Alternator",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 749,
                "desc": "Battery",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 623,
                "desc": "Body, bumper to bumper",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 486,
                "desc": "Brakes",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 744,
                "desc": "Catalytic converter",
                "system": "Catalytic Converter",
                "systemId": 474,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 751,
                "desc": "Charging system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 489,
                "desc": "Cooling and A/C system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 591,
                "desc": "Driveline, drivetrain",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 618,
                "desc": "Exhaust system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 617,
                "desc": "Fluid leaks",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 622,
                "desc": "Fluids and filters",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 757,
                "desc": "General pre-purchase inspection",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 593,
                "desc": "Hybrid vehicle",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 621,
                "desc": "Instruments",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 592,
                "desc": "Lights",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 867,
                "desc": "Nissan Pre-owned",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 863,
                "desc": "Oil change",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 745,
                "desc": "Oxygen sensor",
                "system": "Oxygen Sensor",
                "systemId": 427,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 866,
                "desc": "Pre-alignment",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 807,
                "desc": "Preventive maintenance - 502 force support squadron NAF vehicle fleet",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 764,
                "desc": "Quick lube",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 754,
                "desc": "Road test",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 619,
                "desc": "Starter and charging system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 750,
                "desc": "Starting system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 487,
                "desc": "Steering and suspension system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 490,
                "desc": "Tires",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 752,
                "desc": "Total vehicle and all system",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 868,
                "desc": "Transmission",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 748,
                "desc": "Transmission Inspection",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 746,
                "desc": "Tune-up",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 753,
                "desc": "Under the hood",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 755,
                "desc": "Under vehicle",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 804,
                "desc": "Vehicle safety form 502 FSS",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 594,
                "desc": "Vehicle stability",
                "system": "Road Test",
                "systemId": 475,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 810,
                "desc": "Vehicle walk around",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 485,
                "desc": "Visual inspection",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": null,
                "systemFirebaseKey": null
            },
            {
                "id": 620,
                "desc": "Wipers",
                "system": "Best Practices, General Inspection",
                "systemId": 424,
                "inspectionFlag": true,
                "firebaseKey": "-LDGovCRvp7w9bmw12ii",
                "systemFirebaseKey": "-LDGovCRvp7w9bmw12ii"
            }
        ],
        "inspectionList": [],
        "zoneTime": "2018-08-23T07:21:21.000Z"
    },
    "status": "success"
}
```

Comment: You can use this to generate your model... http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org

Comment: *I have this type of response. How to handle in retrofit2?* Ask to [google](https://www.google.com/). and try your self If any error accrue then you can paste your question in SO. or must read [How to paste good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

First, create the InspectionLibrary object

```
class InspectionLibrary
{
    int id;
    String desc;
    String system;
    int systemId;
    boolean inspectionFlag;
    String firebaseKey;
    String systemFirebaseKey;
}
```

Then, the content object (don't forget to create the InspectionList object).

```
class ResultContent
{
    String customer;
    String vehicle;
    InspectionLibrary[] inspectionLibrary;
    InspectionList[] inspectionList;
    String zoneTime;
}
```

Then, the result object :

```
class ApiResult
{
    ResultContent content;
    String status;
}
```

And finally, from the Api interface, add this method (Don't forget to repalce the text inside the POST annotation):

```
@POST("Path")
Call<ApiResult> getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand... You are making retrofit call and want to get response in such a json parsed form.

For that first you have to make model class using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ Inside package : define your application root package name.  class name : Give class name whatever you want to keep. But ensure this given class name will be root class of your model. As you can see your json have hierarchical model.

Target Language : Java Source type : Json Annotation Type : Gson Check : use double number & include getter and setter.

This is configuration using those you will be able to create Model class.

Let's understand your json : How it will work ?  suppose I took package name : com test example  class name : TestDao

After that I downloaded TestDao-source.zip

Now extract this : You will see Folder code --> test --> example --> Files

Content.java InspectionalLibrary.java TestDao.java

So I hope you understood by this.  let me explain : Once have look at your json .

Step 1 : In your json you have two things content & status which is root key values of your json. So these two things goes into TestDao.java

Step 2 : What is next ? see...  Second hierarchy is "content" which have customer, vehicle, inspectionLibrary, inspectionList, zoneTime. All these key values comes inside "content" that's why your another model class name is content.java

Step 3 : Third hierarchy is "inspectionLibrary" which have id, desc, system, systemId, inspectionFlag, firebaseKey, systemFirebaseKey. All these key values comes inside "Inspectional Library" that's why your another model class name is "inspectionalLibrary.java"

Step 4 :  Four Hierarchy is "inspectionList" which currently don't have any data means showing null. So once there will be data in array format then same like inspectionalLibrary you will have to make another class and write getter setter method of those.

@SerializedName("content") @Expose

Every variable of each model class have these annotation. which means serializedName which indicate that once you use this model class in retrofit then GSON Parser will target "SerializedName("Key_Name")". Means inside bracket whatever written is nothing but key of your json which help GSON to parse your value.

@Expose which help to expose your parsed valued using defined variable.

I hope you understand this is how we have to read json.

Answer (score 0):

Now let's talk about retrofit.

RestAPI.java
This is basically use for make api's call.

```
public class RestClient {

private static TestWebService gitApiInterface ;
private static String baseUrl = "https://example.com" ; // your api base url

public static TestWebService getClient() {
    if (gitApiInterface == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        gitApiInterface = client.create(TestWebService.class);
    }
    return gitApiInterface ;
}

public interface TestWebService
{
    @POST("/subtypeindex/{param1}/{param2}/")
    Call<TestDao> getSampleApiResponse(@Path(value = "param1") String param1,
                                       @Path(value = "param1") String param2);
}
}
```

See inside interface TestWebService, I wrote one method "getSampleApiResponse" which is returning TestDao (Which I earlier explain this is root class of your model). In @POST You can modify your rest of api url except base which you have define at top of class starting. And parameter you can define as per you need. There is different forms of parameter assignment is available. For reference go through retrofit official site.

This is the method which you can call from your activity or fragment. Now here you need to ensure whatever you are returning from interface same class you have map in Call. This is how it will link with your interface and help you to make call on define api's.

```
private void callTestApi()
{
    RestClient.TestWebService service = RestClient.getClient();
    Call<TestDao> callTestApi = service.getSampleApiResponse("param1", "param2");
    callTestApi.enqueue(new Callback<TestDao>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TestDao> call, Response<TestDao> response)
        {
            if(response.raw().code()==200)
            {
                if(response.body().getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                {
                    mUserMenuAdapter = new UserMenuViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
response.body().getContent().getInspectionList());
                    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserMenuAdapter);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Prompt Error 
Msg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Prompt Error 
Msg",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TestDao> call, Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this will help you let understand the basic flow of api call using retrofit And How to read json before consume it.